# How can I change the background color of the arrow in an iOS popover in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, storyboard, popover

When I set the background color of a UIView in the storyboard to a specific color (e.g. black) the arrow of the popup remains unchanged (e.g. white).

How can I change the color of the arrow too?

Comment: If `self.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor` doesn't work, you might want to try to access the window.

Comment: It works if you include the line into the UIViewController which you are using as content for your popover

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the arrow of a popover in the same color like the background color of the popover, add the following line in the "viewDidLoad()" method in your UIViewController (the "popup"):

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor
}
```

[iOS popover with changed background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1pG4.png)